# Trigger DML in oracle database

Tags: oracle, triggers, dml

I have problem with my dml trigger on oracle database.I want to launch trigger when i update first_name or last name on employees table in hr schema. During execution trigger i Have error ORA-00060: Please help. Idon't have any ideas how can i fix it.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9jbT.png)

```
CREATE OR replace TRIGGER up_sal
  BEFORE UPDATE OF first_name, last_name ON employees
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    PRAGMA autonomous_transaction;
    var_sal    employees.salary%TYPE;
    var_avg    NUMBER;
    var_emp_id NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT salary
    INTO   var_sal
    FROM   employees
    WHERE  first_name = :NEW.first_name
            OR last_name = :NEW.last_name;

    SELECT Avg(salary)
    INTO   var_avg
    FROM   employees
    WHERE  department_id IN( :OLD.department_id );

    IF var_sal < var_avg THEN
      var_emp_id := :OLD.employee_id;

      UPDATE employees
      SET    salary = var_avg * 1.1
      WHERE  employee_id = var_emp_id;

      COMMIT;
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Can you explain with words what you want to accomplish with your on update trigger, because your select into statement is probably unnecessary and will raise errors in some cases.

Comment: During update first_name or last_name i want to check if employee salary is smaller then avg_sal in employee's department. If is smaller i want to update salary

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER up_sal
  BEFORE UPDATE OF first_name, last_name ON employees
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
  var_avg employees.salary%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT Avg(salary)
  INTO   var_avg
  FROM   employees
  WHERE  department_id IN( :OLD.department_id );

  IF :NEW.salary < var_avg THEN
    :NEW.salary := var_avg * 1.1;
  END IF;
  
  COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE employees (
  department_id NUMBER,
  first_name    VARCHAR2(20),
  last_name     VARCHAR2(20),
  salary        NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO employees (department_id, first_name, last_name, salary)
SELECT 1, 'Alice', 'Abbot',  90 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Betty', 'Baron',  95 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Carol', 'Count', 105 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Debra', 'Duke',  110 FROM DUAL;
```

Then if you do:

```sql
UPDATE employees
SET first_name = TRIM(first_name),
    last_name  = TRIM(last_name);
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT * FROM employees;
```

Outputs:

> | DEPARTMENT_ID | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | SALARY |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | Alice | Abbot | 110 |
> | 1 | Betty | Baron | 110 |
> | 1 | Carol | Count | 105 |
> | 1 | Debra | Duke | 110 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=d41d525b0f82db1c3105f08986954017)*